# Enable browser action for an event in Google chrome

Tags: plugins, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome extension for capturing the URL.  This is the code for my js file.

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
myFunction(tab.url);
});
function myFunction(tablink) {
alert(tablink);
}
```

Now i can get the URL alert for the page by explicitly clicking on the  `browser action.` I need it to popup the alert whenever i click on any tab in my browser. 
Could you please let me know how to proceed with this?

PS: I am sure i have to use some kind of event listener.

Answer (score 0):

`chrome.tabs.getSelected` is deprecated since Chrome 33. Use [`chrome.tabs.query`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query) instead if needed.

Base on your need to make popup the alert whenever you click on any tab in your browser. You can use [chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener.](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onActivated)

The code I created is as below and it works with me. It popup the alert of current page's url whenever you click on any tab in your browser.

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(activeInfo) {
  //alert("popup");
  chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId, function(tab){
     alert(tab.url);
   });
});
```

Also keep in mind to add `"permissions": ["tabs"],` in your manifest file since it requires access to the url. See here:https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs

Comment: Downvoting, since it does not do what you explicitly say it does.

Comment: @Xan. Thanks for the link. I admire your excellent talent on CWS issues!